# math.floor and math.ceil behaving differently

Tags: python, math

Consider the following question:

```
>>> math.ceil(-122339816.7)
-122339816.0
>>> math.floor(-122339816.7)
-122339817.0
```

According to the definition of math.ceil and math.floor:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

> math.ceil(x) Return the ceiling of x as a float, the smallest integer
>   value greater than or equal to x.

For math.ceil, the smallest integer value greater than or equal to -122339816.7 is -122339817.0. So, why isnt python giving the correct answer?

Comment: Python is correct. `-1.5 < -1`, `-122339816.7 < -122339816.0`. If you want to truncate the fractional part, use `int`.

Comment: ah yes. my bad . thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smallest means closest to negative infinity, not closest to zero.